# webstorm + typescript "unresolved variable" after adding reference path

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I'm using the latest WebStorm EAP 7 130.958.

I have had this buggy behavior since version 6 came out with Typescript support. The problem in the below example code applies "unresolved variable" to BaseClass in the ExtendedClass.ts the moment I add ...

```
///<reference path="./Interfaces.ts"/>
```

If I remove reference path the error goes away. This happens any time I extend from a class imported from a node module ONLY when a reference path exists. How did this make it all the way through 6 to 7?

Interfaces.ts

```
interface IBaseClass {
    str:string;
}
```

BaseClass.ts

```
///<reference path="./Interfaces.ts"/>
export class BaseClass implements IBaseClass{
    constructor(public str:string){
        return str+str;
    }
}
```

ExtendedClass.ts

```
///<reference path="./Interfaces.ts"/>
import baseClassModule = module("./BaseClass");

class ExtendedClass extends baseClassModule.BaseClass{
    constructor(public str:string){
        super(str);
    }
}

var extendedClass:ExtendedClass = new ExtendedClass("yo");

console.log(extendedClass);
```

[image: No error present]

[image: Error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug. You can add `///<reference path="./BaseClass.ts"/>` in your ExtendedClass.ts file as a workaround now. Please watch [WEB-7645](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7645) to get notified when it will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Modify it to "export interface IBaseClass" and on the other side you need to require it.

At runtime you might get an error loading a js file not there. If so make an empty js file.

My recommendation : do not have a file just with interfaces when using requirejs/commonjs

Comment: But I cant reference node.d.ts as the entire web recommends... how can that be right?